# std::ifstream setting fail() even when no error

Tags: c++, c++11

Using GCC 4.7.3 on Cygwin 1.7.24.  Compiler options include: -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra

I am working on a command line application and I needed to be able to load and save a set of strings so I wrote a quick wrapper class around std::set to add load and save methods.

```
// KeySet.h

#ifndef KEYSET_H
#define KEYSET_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

inline bool file_exists (const std::string& filename)
{
/*
    Utility routine to check existance of a file.  Returns true or false,
    prints an error and exits with status 2 on an error.
*/
    struct  stat buffer;
    int     error = stat(filename.c_str(), &buffer);
    if (error == 0) return true;
    if (errno == ENOENT) return false;
    std::cerr << "Error while checking for '" << filename << "': " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    exit (2);
}

class KeySet
{
private:
    std::string             filename;
    std::set<std::string>   keys;

public:
    KeySet() {}
    KeySet(const std::string Pfilename) : filename(Pfilename) {}

    void set_filename (const std::string Pfilename) {filename = Pfilename;}
    std::string get_filename () {return filename;}
    auto size () -> decltype(keys.size()) {return keys.size();}
    auto cbegin() -> decltype(keys.cbegin()) {return keys.cbegin();}
    auto cend() -> decltype(keys.cend()) {return keys.cend();}
    auto insert(const std::string key) -> decltype(keys.insert(key)) {return keys.insert(key);}
    void load ();
    void save ();
};

void KeySet::load ()
{
    if (file_exists(filename)) {
        errno = 0;
        std::ifstream   in (filename, std::ios_base::in);

        if (in.fail()) {
            std::cerr << "Error opening '" << filename << "' for reading: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            exit (2);
        }

        std::string     token;
        if (token.capacity() < 32) token.reserve(32);

        while (in >> token) keys.insert(token);

        if (!in.eof()) {
            std::cerr << "Error reading '" << filename << "': " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            exit (2);
        }

        in.clear(); // need to clear flags before calling close
        in.close();
        if (in.fail()) {
            std::cerr << "Error closing '" << filename << "': " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

            exit (2);
        }
    }
}

void KeySet::save ()
{
    errno = 0;
    std::ofstream   out (filename, std::ios_base::out);

    if (out.fail()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening '" << filename << "' for writing: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit (2);
    }

    for (auto key = keys.cbegin(), end = keys.cend(); key != end; ++key) {
        out << *key << std::endl;
    }

    out.close();
    if (out.fail()) {
        std::cerr << "Error writing '" << filename << "': " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        exit (2);
    }
}

#endif

//
```

Here's a quick program to test the load method.

```
// ks_test.cpp

#include "KeySet.h"

int main()
{
    KeySet          test;
    std::string     filename = "foo.keys.txt";

    test.set_filename(filename);

    test.load();

    for (auto key = test.cbegin(), end = test.cend(); key != end; ++key) {
        std::cout << *key << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The data file just has "one two three" in it.

When I go to run the test program, I get the following error from my test program:

```
$ ./ks_test
Error closing 'foo.keys.txt': No error
```

Both [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/close) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/close/) say that the close method should set the fail bit on error.  The save method works fine, and the load method works correctly if I comment out the error check after the close.  Should this really work or have I misunderstood how close is supposed to work?  Thanks in advance.

Edited to clarify, fix typo's and adjust code per Joachim Pileborg's and Konrad Rudolph's comments.

Edited to add solution to the code.

Comment: `file_exists` doesn’t exist in C++ for a good reason: it is broken. Remove it, it serves absolutely **no** purpose – just try reading the file instead. Apart from that the function shouldn’t `exit` – at most it should throw an exception. And remove the `__attribute__ ((unused)`, and remove the variable. You can call `insert` without assigning the result to a variable. At the moment the code looks deliberately obfuscated.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I didn't mention (but will add) that this is code excerpted from a larger command line application.  `file_exists` is not broken, it works fine and is used multiple times in the application.  I reused it here to make the error checking cleaner since it is not an error if the file doesn't exist.  I would agree about throwing an exception if this were a library routine, but printing an error to STDERR and exiting with a non-zero code is convention for command line apps.  I would love to learn how to call `insert` without assigning to a variable. Would you please post an example?

Comment: I didn’t mean that *your* implementation was broken, but that the file existence check is broken by design since file systems are inherently concurrent, and checking file existence is a race condition. That said, I agree that your usage is useful. Still, using `exit` here is a huge problem. *Do* throw an exception instead (and catch it in `main`, and then return from there): otherwise, not all objects’ destructors will get called, leading to unintended consequences. As for insert, just call `keys.insert(token);` – where’s the problem?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm with you now (caffeine hadn't kicked in yet). I do agree that checking file existence prior to opening is a race condition, in this specific application it is a non-issue. The fact that `exit` doesn't unwind the stack and destroy my automatic objects is a real bummer - I now get to go through all of my code and turn my exits into exceptions. The problem with just calling `keys.insert(token)` **was** back on the compilers I learned to program C/C++ on, using a non-void function in a void context generated (at least) a compile time warning. It works now - is that a good thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the close method for ifstream (and I assume all other IO objects) **DOES NOT**  clear the error flags before closing the file.  This means you need to add an explicit clear() call before you close the stream after end of file if you are checking for errors during the close.  In my case, I added `in.clear();` just before the `in.close();` call and it is working as I expect.

Answer (score 6):

You have two errors here: The first is about how you do your reading, more specifically the loop for reading. The `eof` flag will not be set until *after* you tried to read and the read failed. Instead you should do like this:

```
while (in >> token) { ... }
```

Otherwise you will loop one time to many and try to read beyond the end of the file.

The second problem is the one you notice, and it depends on the the first problem. Since you try to read beyond the end of the file, the stream will set `failbit` causing `in.fail()` to return `true` even though there is no real error.

Comment: I've re-written my input loop as you suggest (that's the same idiom I use in Perl, so I'm not sure why I didn't do that in the first place) and added the appropriate error check once `in >> token` returns false, but I'm still getting an error when I close the stream.